# Better to check undefined property or set as null?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, undefined

It's easier to explain in code that in words, so given the following scenarios:

```
// one

var myClass = function(a, b)
{
    if(a) this.a = a;
    if(b) this.b = b;
}

// two

var myClass = function(a, b)
{
    this.a = a || null;
    this.b = b || null;
}
```

And say you have this method that gets called constantly (many times / second)

```
myClass.prototype.doSomething = function()
{
    if(this.a) // do something
    if(this.b) // so something else
};
```

In first case you check for an undefined property while in second for an existing one, but with the value `null`.

Which case performs better in JavaScript?

Comment: If you really want to know performance numbers, then you should make your own jsperf (will take about 3 mins) and run it in whatever browsers you think are important.  The ONLY way to answer performance questions is to test in the browsers you think are relevant.

Comment: Keep in mind that both of these methods (one and two) do not work if an expected and legal value for a or b in the constructor is a falsey value like (0, "", false, etc...).  To allow those values, you have to explicitly test a and b in the arguments for `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I setup the test in an optimal fashion, but this site is great for benchmarking:

http://jsperf.com/or-pipe-versus-if

The results I got show using IF statements instead of the OR operator to set defaults performs 6% better

Comment: I tried the same test with Chrome/WinXP, and the "OR w/o values" was the fastest case while every other case was either 92% or 93% slower - i.e., all the others were about the same. A real-world case would presumably have false or not-provided values only some of the time though, and I think the OP also wanted to take into account the speed of later use of those properties (which may or may not have been set at that point they were tested). Still, +1 for setting up the test and for providing the link to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are testing whether the a and b parameters in the constructor have a "truthy" value. Which means in both cases if you pass in, say, 0 or an empty string, or (obviously) false then that value will be discarded. The difference is the first case doesn't create the property on the object, while the second one defaults to null instead.

Either way you still have to test the property when you actually come to use it in `doSomething()`, and your `if (this.a)` test will work whether the property hasn't been set, has been set to null, or has been explicitly set to undefined.

If you don't want to return an error if the values aren't provided I'd be inclined to just set them directly:

```
var myClass = function(a, b)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

If the value isn't provided in the parameter the property will be created but set to undefined, which will still work exactly the same way in your test in `doSomething()`, but you'd be saving an if or || test with the added advantage of not throwing away 0, empty string or false values. This way the constructor is neater...

As far as actual performance comparisons you really have to setup a proper test (e.g., at jsperf.com). If I had to guess I'd say on average the `if(a) this.a=a;` version would be faster since it does the assignment only when a is truthy, but guessing about performance is a bad plan. Until you test it *in different browsers* you won't really know - it may be that one way is faster in IE while another is faster in Chrome. If you set up a test be sure to compare with a straight assignment similar to what I showed above.

EDIT: I just saw the other answer that found a 6% performance difference. For such a minimal difference, and noting that as I mentioned above the performance difference *may* be reversed in some browsers,  I think you are better off coding whatever makes the most sense for your processing requirements and just not worrying about performance. Either way (or all three ways if you include my answer) is clear and simple and performs well, they just don't quite do the same thing...